# Linking in html5

Tags: html, web

I am unable to link to html5 section within same page.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="services">Services</a> </li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>`

<div id="contact">
    <h2 id="contact">How to find Us?</h2>
```

Why is not going to the section "Contact" on the same page but it's trying to open new page: "http://example.com/contact ?

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique. Use an id only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>

<div id="contact">my contact</div>
```

you forgot the #

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#yourAnchor">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<a name="yourAnchor"></a>      
<div id="contact">
   <h2>How to find Us?</h2>
 </div>
```

Try this.

Comment: double using `id="contact"` will not work. id's are unique, otherwise you will get side effects you don't want to have. and your solution did not work. please test it if you are not sure

Comment: @TypedSource I agree, the duplicate id might cause issues. You should post it as an answer because that is more correct than existing answers.

Comment: Yes you both right missed that because just copied and pasted his code. I am editing immediately now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Yes, I forgot to put # (due too many changes/toubleshooting).

I've put the # and I've used unique id for href -  that worked like a charm!

Thanks again @TypedSource and @user3713452 for your help!